# 2d character generator for android games

Tags: android, game-design, animation

I am a developer, and not an artist. is there a 2d character generator that i can feed one picture and it will generate the proper files to be displayed for a running animation?

Comment: 3d, 2d? If there are bones involved yes.

Comment: please check out my edit - 2d animation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no magical piece of software to do your art for you.

However there are tools to make it easier and I can recommend Spine. It was used at a studio I interned at. The artist there really liked it and it integrated well into Unity.

http://esotericsoftware.com/

Here's a tutorial that said artist wrote:

http://www.darkwindmedia.com/wulverblade-intro-to-skeletal-animations/

It's pretty straightforward but it should give you an idea about what the tool can do.

There are libraries to integrate Spine with Unity, Cocos2D, LibGDX and many more: http://esotericsoftware.com/spine-runtimes